# Spring Hibernate error in GAE (Google App Engine)

Tags: spring, hibernate, google-app-engine

I am having following error in GAE (Google App Engine), when I am trying to run Spring, Hibernate application. Is it due to userid & password? I can't figure it out. I've changed password too..... Any help is appreciated.

javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'org.hibernate.exception.DataException' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = org.hibernate.exception.DataException: Cannot open connection at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:665) at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:126) at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter$ValueWriter$8.write(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:153) at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeValue(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:585) at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeClass(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:755) at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeImpl(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:794) at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:667) at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:126) at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter$ValueWriter$8.write(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:153) at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeValue(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:585) at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponse(RPC.java:605) at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:393) at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:579) at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208) at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248) at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511) at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166) at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125) at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157) at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35) at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157) at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60) at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157) at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43) at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157) at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388) at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216) at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182) at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765) at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418) at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:266) at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152) at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326) at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542) at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923) at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76) at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404) at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146) at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:446) at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437) at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444) at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:188) at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308) at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300) at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441) at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Comment: It's too hard!  Does the software have any possibly related source code that you could add to the question?  Or if that's too confidential, what was it doing just before this stack trace spewed out?  Did it ever work?  Think of [the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints).

Comment: Well, This never worked on GAE. Code is working fine on my personal computer. I believe it has something to do with URL of Google Cloud SQL. On the local computer I am using MYSQL and it is working fine. I am using following url for Hibernate/Spring connection in the applicationcontext.xml file. <property name="url" value="jdbc:google:rdbms://cloudsql/zrfootballsite:cricdb-dev/cricdb?user=root" />

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace mentions `JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter` which relates to the MySQL that you commented on.  Start by ensuring you have followed the [Cloud SQL](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/) guidelines and that you have enabled billing.

In the absence of source code to discuss, I suggest a process of potential problem elimination.  Deploy and run the documented starter Cloud SQL app on AppEngine to verify your account and permissions.  After Cloud SQL works, add and test the Spring framework dependencies to verify that they integrate properly.  After Spring also works, add your original project content.